# How do i create an array data type in Strapi?

Tags: backend, content-management-system, strapi

I am very new to Strapi and Next.js, I am in the process of building a blog using Next and for the CMS, I will be using Strapi. I have created a new content type of Post and defined variables such as title, date, published etc. which was fairly easy and straightforward. My Post content type has categories as well in the format of:

```
categories: ["programming", "Technology"]
```

How do I define such a data type in Strapi, so that it returns an array of categories?

I have tried selecting JSON and defining the categories as:

```json
[
  "Programming",
  "Technology"
]
```

but I do not want non-tech end users dealing with JSON and manually creating arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I would suggest that you create a Category collection type.
and you create a relation between your Post and your Category collection type.

In your case, you will need a many to many relation since a Post can have multiple Catgories, and a Category can be related to many Posts.

Then you will be able to add all your Categories in the Content Manager.
(if you want some Admin Users to not manage Categories, make sure you allow Read, and disable Edit/Delete)

This would match your need, and avoid dealing with a JSON in the Content Manager.